# How to use the subjunctive mood here, where it seems like it might mix subjunctive and not subjunctive?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

In the following sentence, how should the "to be" verbs be conjugated since the sentence is in the subjunctive mood?

> If it went over their heads once, then they’d soon forget what it was that was going over their heads.

Comment: The main problem is the twinning of semelfactive (one-off) and continuous / iterative structures. *'If the plane flew over their heads once, they'd soon forget what it was that was habitually flying over their heads.'

Comment: I don't follow you. I can't see a subjunctive clause in your example. It's a conditional construction with no grammatical problems, as far as I can see.

Comment: Do you want "if it were to go over their heads once, then they would soon forget what it was that was going over their heads"? But I will second Edwin's objection to mixing the one-time and habitual structures.

Comment: This looks to be what ESL/EFL books call the [second conditional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if), not the subjunctive. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) explains when English subjunctives are actually used, or you can search this site for "subjunctive"; *if* clauses use a subjunctive in some Indo-European languages but not in English.

Comment: Just so you know, no one (sorry, only very few people) in standard English uses the subjunctive any more. Even in academic writing.

Comment: @Pound Hash ELU is aimed at linguists; the teminology has been used fairly regularly here.